# Plotting multiple groups of shaded subplots for unique ids in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe with multiple unique id,s as data sample is shown below.

- I am trying to plot multiple group of shaded plots according to the
  unique ids. I tried but only successful to get single plot.
- Also, the output should print the aggregated(sum) value of forecast for each unique id at the top of the plot as shown in the image.

**I tried for single plot:**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r"data/data.csv", usecols = ['Hour', 'unqiue_id','Forecast'], header = 0)

X1 = df.Forecast
mu = X1.mean()
sigma = X1.std()

timestep = df.Hour

X1_plus_sigma = X1 + sigma
X1_minus_sigma = X1 - sigma

plt.plot(timestep, X1, color = 'blue')
plt.fill_between(timestep, X1_plus_sigma, X1_minus_sigma, alpha = 0.2, color = 'blue')

plt.show()
```

### `sample_data.csv`

```py
Hour    unqiue_id   Forecast
1   105590  0.428732899
2   105590  0.501308875
3   105590  0.491805242
4   105590  0.392900424
5   105590  0.442624008
6   105590  0.411723392
7   105590  0.397455466
8   105590  0.400126642
9   105590  0.444411425
10  105590  0.423408925
11  105590  0.759687642
12  105590  2.166908125
13  105590  2.153370175
14  105590  2.053740002
15  105590  2.095005501
16  105590  2.153214908
17  105590  2.210168766
18  105590  2.122148284
19  105590  1.9024695
20  105590  2.255718026
21  105590  2.258879807
22  105590  0.480089583
23  105590  1.551103332
24  105590  1.512505375
1   105641  0.38613255
2   105641  0.377992208
3   105641  0.335113249
4   105641  0.276971167
5   105641  0.25582105
6   105641  0.163678899
7   105641  0.252606425
8   105641  0.234117893
9   105641  0.253319091
10  105641  0.247366499
11  105641  0.223124576
12  105641  0.327788192
13  105641  0.337751692
14  105641  0.404392083
15  105641  0.464561699
16  105641  0.461135366
17  105641  0.418630009
18  105641  0.442330958
19  105641  0.439433858
20  105641  0.355377993
21  105641  0.631322225
22  105641  0.402346984
23  105641  0.371785651
24  105641  0.4536452
```

**Expected output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69030079/9214357):

> The shaded area around the lines represent the 95% confidence
> interval. **In order to have this area you should have more than one
> observation for each time point**, so it is possible to compute a
> standard deviation and a CI for each time point. But in data you
> provided there are only one observation for each time point. You can
> do draw an *similar* plot, by computing the standard deviation and sum
> and subtract it from the columns you want to plot. **Pay attention!**
> This is not the confidence interval (for which you need more
> observation), it's an interval 2 times standard deviation wide around
> mean value for each time point. Moreover it keeps constant width along
> time axis. I honestly doubt this is a useful plot to use, since area
> width it's constant during time and area width it's 2 times the
> standard deviation, which is computed *along* time. In short: you
> shouldn't use this plot and provide more observations for each time
> point in order to compute a proper confidence interval.

*However*, in order to draw the plot you want, you have to compute the standard deviation of each `unique_id` and store it in a column:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'data/data.csv')
df['unique_id'] = df['unique_id'].astype(str)

std = df.groupby(by = 'unique_id')['Forecast'].std()
df = df.set_index('unique_id')
df['std'] = std
df = df.reset_index()
```

```
   unique_id  Hour  Forecast       std
0     105590     1  0.428733  0.824710
1     105590     2  0.501309  0.824710
2     105590     3  0.491805  0.824710
3     105590     4  0.392900  0.824710
4     105590     5  0.442624  0.824710
...
43    105641    20  0.355378  0.104879
44    105641    21  0.631322  0.104879
45    105641    22  0.402347  0.104879
46    105641    23  0.371786  0.104879
47    105641    24  0.453645  0.104879
```

Then you can plot on the same axis (no need for a subplot) looping over `unique_id` and shading an area wide `2*k` times the standard deviation:

```
k = 0.2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for id in df['unique_id'].unique():
    df_filt = df[df['unique_id'] == id]
    ax.plot(df_filt['Hour'], df_filt['Forecast'], label = f"ID = {id}   Aggregated sum = {df_filt['Forecast'].sum():.0f}")
    ax.fill_between(df_filt['Hour'], df_filt['Forecast'] + k*df_filt['std'], df_filt['Forecast'] - k*df_filt['std'], alpha = 0.5)

ax.legend(frameon = True)

plt.show()
```

### Complete Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv(r'data/data.csv')
df['unique_id'] = df['unique_id'].astype(str)

std = df.groupby(by = 'unique_id')['Forecast'].std()
df = df.set_index('unique_id')
df['std'] = std
df = df.reset_index()


k = 0.2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for id in df['unique_id'].unique():
    df_filt = df[df['unique_id'] == id]
    ax.plot(df_filt['Hour'], df_filt['Forecast'], label = f"ID = {id}   Aggregated sum = {df_filt['Forecast'].sum():.0f}")
    ax.fill_between(df_filt['Hour'], df_filt['Forecast'] + k*df_filt['std'], df_filt['Forecast'] - k*df_filt['std'], alpha = 0.5)

ax.legend(frameon = True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Alternative with subplots:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, len(df['unique_id'].unique()))

for i, id in enumerate(df['unique_id'].unique(), 0):
    df_filt = df[df['unique_id'] == id]
    ax[i].plot(df_filt['Hour'], df_filt['Forecast'])
    ax[i].fill_between(df_filt['Hour'], df_filt['Forecast'] + k*df_filt['std'], df_filt['Forecast'] - k*df_filt['std'], alpha = 0.5)
    ax[i].set_title(f"ID = {id}\nAggregated sum = {df_filt['Forecast'].sum():.0f}")

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Subplot aggregation in 3 columns:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(df['unique_id'].unique())//3 + 1, 3)

for ax, id in zip(axes.flatten(), df['unique_id'].unique()):
    df_filt = df[df['unique_id'] == id]
    ax.plot(df_filt['Hour'], df_filt['Forecast'])
    ax.fill_between(df_filt['Hour'], df_filt['Forecast'] + k*df_filt['std'], df_filt['Forecast'] - k*df_filt['std'], alpha = 0.5)
    ax.set_title(f"ID = {id}\nAggregated sum = {df_filt['Forecast'].sum():.0f}")
```

Comment: Thank you. The code is not calculating the correct std. It prints zero for all values. Also, I am trying to get multiple subplots for each unique id.

Comment: In data you provided the column is named `unqiue_id`, it should be `unique_id`, isn't it? Is a typo?

Comment: Do you still have issue with std?

Comment: issue with subplots https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUqwL.png

Comment: I have 35 unique ids, so I want to wrap up three subplots in every column

Comment: If there 35 unique ids, there should be 35 subplots for each unique id.

Comment: Updated answer. However 35 subplots will be always too many, whatever manner you organize them. You should consider to plot some of them in the same plot with different color and a legend

Comment: I am trying to get similar kind of subplots https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67164867/how-to-create-multiple-groups-of-subplots-for-many-unique-ids/67169586#67169586

Comment: Instead of shading the plots with `std`, is it possible to keep equal shading for all subplots with ` X1_plus_sigma = X1 + k*sigma` and ` X1_minus_sigma = X1 - k*sigma`  ?